# How do you sort du output by size?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, disk-usage, sort, units

How do you sort `du -sh /dir/*` by size? I read one site that said use `| sort -n` but that's obviously not right. Here's an example that is wrong.

```
[~]# du -sh /var/* | sort -n
0       /var/mail
1.2M    /var/www
1.8M    /var/tmp
1.9G    /var/named
2.9M    /var/run
4.1G    /var/log
8.0K    /var/account
8.0K    /var/crash
8.0K    /var/cvs
8.0K    /var/games
8.0K    /var/local
8.0K    /var/nis
8.0K    /var/opt
8.0K    /var/preserve
8.0K    /var/racoon
12K     /var/aquota.user
12K     /var/portsentry
16K     /var/ftp
16K     /var/quota.user
20K     /var/yp
24K     /var/db
28K     /var/empty
32K     /var/lock
84K     /var/profiles
224M    /var/netenberg
235M    /var/cpanel
245M    /var/cache
620M    /var/lib
748K    /var/spool
```

Comment: I knew I'd [seen this before](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size). The [highest-voted answer there](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/62412#62412) isn't very good, [but](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/62428#62428) [others](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/62418#62418) [are](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/62422#62422) [better](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/62522#62522).

Comment: The accepted answer `sort -h` worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Aug 2017.    First I find my mounted drive by `cd /mnt` (mounted by UUID in fstab).  Then I do `du >~/dumnt.out`  then `sort -h ~/dumnt.out >~/dumntsort.out` then I can do `tail ~/dumntsort.out to see the largest space hogs.

Comment: Very similar in what is to be accomplished:
[Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429)

Answer (score 392, accepted):

If you have GNU coreutils (common in most Linux distributions), you can use

```
du -sh -- * | sort -h
```

The `-h` option tells `sort` that the input is the human-readable format (number with unit; 1024-based so that 1023 is considered less than 1K which happens to match what GNU `du -h` does).

This feature [was added to GNU Core Utilities 7.5 in Aug 2009](http://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?func=detailitem&item_id=2565).

> **Note:**
>
> If you are using an older version of Mac OSX, you need to install coreutils with `brew install coreutils`， then use `gsort` as drop-in replacement of `sort`.
>
> Newer versions of macOS (verified on Mojave) support `sort -h` natively.

Comment: note: add `-r` to sort, if you want the big ones at the top

Comment: On OSX you can install `coreutils` via `brew` and add the bin folder to your `PATH` into your *rc* file, and `-h` should be available.

Comment: Oh - thank you for the -r reminder.  that means I don't need the `tail` command to see the hogs.

Comment: A variant of this is easier to edit on the terminal: `sort -hr <(du -sh /absolute/path/*)`. For anyone zooming on a directory with a full disk, it also reverses the order.

Answer (score 56):

Try using the -k flag to count 1K blocks intead of using human-readable.  Then, you have a common unit and can easily do a numeric sort.

```
du -ck | sort -n
```

You don't explictly require human units, but if you did, then there are a bunch of ways to do it.  Many seem to use the 1K block technique above, and then make a second call to du.

https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

If you want to see the KB units added, use:

```
du -k | sed -e 's_^\([0-9]*\)_\1 KB_' | sort -n
```

Comment: nice not to have to install something else to get the results I need

Answer (score 19):

If you don't have a [recent version of GNU coreutils](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-do-you-sort-du-output-by-size/4682#4682), you can call `du` without `-h` to get sortable output, and produce human-friendly output with a little postprocessing. This has the advantage of working even if your version of `du` doesn't have the `-h` flag.

```
du -k | sort -n | awk '
    function human(x) {
        if (x<1000) {return x} else {x/=1024}
        s="kMGTEPZY";
        while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
            {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
        return int(x+0.5) substr(s,1,1)
    }
    {gsub(/^[0-9]+/, human($1)); print}'
```

If you want SI suffixes (i.e. multiples of 1000 rather than 1024), change 1024 to 1000 in the `while` loop body. (Note that that 1000 in the condition is intended, so that you get e.g. `1M` rather than `1000k`.)

If your `du` has an option to display sizes in bytes (e.g. `-b` or `-B 1` — note that this may have the side effect of counting actual file sizes rather than disk usage), add a space to the beginning of `s` (i.e. `s=" kMGTEPYZ";`), or add `if (x<1000) {return x} else {x/=1024}` at the beginning of the `human` function.

Displaying a decimal digit for numbers in the range 1–10 is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This is has been the one out of the box solution I've found to work on both linux and mac. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have `sort -h` you can do this:

```
du -sh * | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\t/\1B\t/' | sed 's/\(.\t\)/\t\1/' | sed 's/G\t/Z\t/' | sort -n -k 2d,2 -k 1n,1 | sed 's/Z\t/G\t/'
```

This gets the du list, separates the suffix, and sorts using that. Since there is no suffix for <1K, the first sed adds a B (for byte). The second sed adds a delimiter between the digit and the suffix. The third sed converts G to Z so that it's bigger than M; if you have terabyte files, you'll have to convert G to Y and T to Z. Finally, we sort by the two columns, then we replace the G suffix.

Comment: Awesome effort, but this doesn't come close to working for me.

Answer (score 7):

On OS X, you can install the needed coreutils via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install coreutils
```

With this you'll have `gsort`, which includes the `-h` command line parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Since Mac OS X doesn't have the `-h` option for `sort` (I was probably using Mavericks or Yosemite), so I tried and learned `sed` and `awk` for a first attempt:

```
du -sk * | sort -g | awk '{ numBytes = $1 * 1024; numUnits = split("B K M G T P", unit); num = numBytes; iUnit = 0; while(num >= 1024 && iUnit + 1 < numUnits) { num = num / 1024; iUnit++; } $1 = sprintf( ((num == 0) ? "%6d%s " : "%6.1f%s "), num, unit[iUnit + 1]); print $0; }'
```

it is a long line.  Expanded, it is:

```
du -sk * | sort -g | awk '{ 

    numBytes = $1 * 1024; 
    numUnits = split("B K M G T P", unit); 
    num = numBytes; 
    iUnit = 0; 

    while(num >= 1024 && iUnit + 1 < numUnits) { 
        num = num / 1024; 
        iUnit++; 
    } 

    $1 = sprintf( ((num == 0) ? "%6d%s " : "%6.1f%s "), num, unit[iUnit + 1]);
    print $0; 

}'
```

I tried it on Mac OS X Mavericks, Yosemite, Ubuntu 2014-04 with `awk` being the default `awk` (which is `nawk`, because both `awk` and `nawk` point to `/usr/bin/mawk`) or gawk, and they all worked.

Here is a sample of the output on a Mac:

```
     0B  bar
     0B  foo
   4.0K  wah
  43.0M  Documents
   1.2G  Music
   2.5G  Desktop
   4.7G  Movies
   5.6G  VirtualBox VMs
   9.0G  Dropbox
  11.7G  Library
  21.2G  Pictures
  27.0G  Downloads
```

instead of `du -sk *`, I saw in @Stefan's answer where the grand total is also displayed, and without traversing any filesystem mount point, by using `du -skcx *`

Answer (score 4):

This little Perl script does the trick. Save it as `duh` (or whatever you want) and call it with `duh /dir/*`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @line;

sub to_human_readable {
        my ($number) = @_;
        my @postfix = qw( k M G T P );
        my $post;
        my $divide = 1;
        foreach (@postfix) {
                $post = $_;
                last if (($number / ($divide * 1024)) < 1);
                $divide = $divide * 1024;
        }
        $number = int($number/$divide + 0.5);
        return $number . $post;
}

sub trimlengthright {
        my ($txt, $len) = @_;
        if ( length($txt) >= $len ) {
                $txt = substr($txt,0,$len - 1) . " ";
        } else {
                $txt = $txt . " " x ($len - length($txt));
        }
        return $txt;
}

sub trimlengthleft {
        my ($txt, $len) = @_;
        if ( length($txt) >= $len ) {
                $txt = substr($txt,0,$len - 1) . " ";
        } else {
                $txt = " " x ($len - length($txt)) . $txt;
        }
        return $txt;
}

open(DF,"du -ks @ARGV | sort -n |");
while (<DF>) {
        @line = split;
        print &trimlengthleft(&to_human_readable($line[0]),5)," "; # size
        print &trimlengthright($line[1],70),"\n"; # directory
}
close DF;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Command:**

`du -ah . | sort -k1 -h | tail -n 50`

**Explanation:**

- List size of all files/folders recursively in the current directory in human-readable form

`du -ah .`

- Sort the human-readable size which is present in the first column and keep the largest 50

`sort -k1 -h | tail -n 50`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use on Ubuntu 10.04, CentOS 5.5, FreeBSD and Mac OS X.

I borrowed the idea from [www.geekology.co.za/](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/checking-directory-sizes-on-bash-command-line/) and [earthinfo.org](http://www.earthinfo.org/linux-disk-usage-sorted-by-size-and-human-readable/), as well as the infamous [ducks](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/15) from "Linux Server Hacks" by O'Reilly. I am still adapting it to my needs. This is still a work in progress (As in, I was working on this on the train this morning.):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
ducks () {
    du -cks -x | sort -n | while read size fname; do
        for unit in k M G T P E Z Y; do
            if [ $size -lt 1024 ]; then
                echo -e "${size}${unit}\t${fname}"
                break
            fi
            size=$((size/1024))
        done
    done
}
ducks > .ducks && tail .ducks
```

Here's the output:

```
stefan@darwin:~ $ ducks
32M src
42M .cpan
43M .macports
754M    doc
865M    Work
1G  .Trash
4G  Library
17G Downloads
30G Documents
56G total

stefan@darwin:~ $
```

Comment: I think you meant `du -cks -x *` ? (with the asterisk)

Comment: The asterisk is redundant in this usage. Give it a try.

Comment: do you mean putting the first set of code into a file called `ducks`, and then `chmod a+x ducks` and then use `./ducks` to run it?  Then I only see the total disk usage, on both Mac OS X and on Ubuntu 2014-10.  I also tried putting the `ducks() { ...}` definition into `.bashrc` and then use `ducks` to run it, and the same thing on Mac OS X, only see the grand total

Answer (score 1):

Go crazy with this script -

```
$du -k ./* | 
> sort -nr |
> awk '
> {split("KB,MB,GB",size,",");}
> {x = 1;while ($1 >= 1024) {$1 = $1 / 1024;x = x + 1} $1 = sprintf("%-4.2f%s", $1, size[x]); print $0;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of GNU `sort -h`, this should work in most UNIX environments:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 <(du -sk /dir/* 2>/dev/null | sort -k2,2) <(du -sh /dir/* 2>/dev/null | sort -k2,2) | sort -nk2,2 | awk '{ print $3 "\t" $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one handles filenames with whitespace or apostrophes, and works on systems which do not support `xargs -d` or `sort -h`:

```
du -s * | sort -n | cut -f2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} du -sh "{}"
```

which results in:

```
368K    diskmanagementd
392K    racoon
468K    coreaudiod
472K    securityd
660K    sshd
3.6M    php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sort the output in decreasing order of size:

```
du -sh /var/* | sort -k 1rn
```

This will sort the output in increasing order of size:

```
du -sh /var/* | sort -k 1n
```

PS : this can be used to sort by any column but that column values should be in same format

Comment: No. `sort -k1rn` is equivalent to `sort -rn` and just sorts numerically based on the initial sequence of decimal digits on each line. It doesn't understand floating point, and it doesn't understand the `k`, `M`, `G`... suffixes. 10.1k would be considered greater than 1.23G

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Solaris!

```
du -kh | sort -nk1 | grep [0-9]K && du -kh | sort -nk1 | grep [0-9]M && du -kh | sort -nk1 | grep [0-9]G
```

This will output all directory sizes recursively, at the bottom will be largest directory in Gigabytes and at the top smallest in Kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest is at the bottom:

```
du -sh * | sort -h
```

Answer (score -1):

To sort by size in MB

```
du --block-size=MiB --max-depth=1 path | sort -n
```

Comment: The user wants to get the output of `du -h` (human readable output) sorted numerically.  You're not providing an answer to that.  You may also want to link your UNIX-SE account with the other accounts you have on the other SE sites.

Answer (score -2):

This script is even easier:

```
for i in G M K; do du -h -d1 / | grep [0-9]$i | sort -n; done
```

Answer (score -2):

for OSX

```
du -h -k  {PATH} | sort -n
```

Comment: isn't the `-k` just cancelling `-h` and if so how does this provide the human readable output requested by the OP.