# How can I find the three largest files under a directory?

Tags: files, stat

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240424/674 shows a way to find the three most recent changed files (directly or indirectly) under a directory.

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; | sort -nr | awk 'NR==1,NR==3 {print $2}'
```

I try to find the three largest files under a directory by replacing `stat -c '%Y %n'` with `stat -c '%B %n'`. 
but it doesn't seem to work correctly. because:

```
 %b - Number of blocks allocated (see ‘%B’)
 %B - The size in bytes of each block reported by ‘%b’
```

My guess is that `%b` doesn't report the size of a file, but I am not sure.

So what shall I do?

Comment: [using zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130881/117549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%b does report the size of the file, but it reports in blocks. That may or not be good enough for your purposes. You can always use `ls -l` to get bytes if you want:

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -l | sort -n -k5 | tail -n 3
```

If filenames contain white spaces, then the standard solution is

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | ...
```

The `-print0` makes `find` use a null byte as a separator between the names, which is then used as the separator with `xargs -0`.

Comment: Thanks. My filenames contain whitespaces. Would `find . -type f -exec ls -lh {} \; | sort -h -k5 | tail -n 3` be better?

Comment: Maybe - I generally prefer xargs because I find the `find -exec` syntax yucky. I expanded the answer to include a solution that uses xargs.

Comment: If your `find` has `-print0`, it probably has `-ls` as well.

Comment: Using xargs with find is an artefact from the 1980s. David Korn introduced execplus in 1989 for SVr4. The only find implementations without -ls are on AIX and HP-UX. Find -ls has been introduced in 1988 with SunOS/4.0 this is 30 years ago now...