# Extract files from a directory and save the files' names and sizes in KB in a CSV file

Tags: shell-script, files, find, io-redirection

I want to retrieve all the .log files from the directory /var/log, store the results in a csv file along with each log file's respective file size
in kB.

I started by getting the files using find:

```
find . -type f -name "*.log"
```

how to save them in the file?

Comment: What did you try beyond running `find`?

Comment: GNU find has `-printf` which may be useful

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -name '*.log' -printf '%p,%s\n'
```

That will print the filename and the file's size in bytes, separated by a comma.  Use `%f` instead of `%p` if you only want the file's basename (i.e. without the path).

To display as kilobytes (units of 10^3, "KB") or kibibytes (units of 2^10, "KiB"), you'll need to post-process the output.  See [A standard tool to convert a byte-count into human KiB MiB etc; like du, ls1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1) for several ways of doing this.  Using `awk` or `perl` is probably easiest because you only want to modify the 2nd field of each line.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my best guess and then put the contents in a file in your home directory called var-log.csv

```
find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec ls -s {} \; > ~/var-log.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
ls -l --block-size=K *.log | awk {'print $9","$5'} > nameSize.csv
```

Comment: This only works sometimes.  Something that only works some of the time is broken.  [Don't Parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score -1):

ls -l will give you the all the data you need and more:

> : ls -l /var/log/*.log
>       ...
>       -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123456 Jul 11 17:28 /var/log/xinetd.log
>       ...

Then you can extract the fields you need using awk:

> : ls -l /var/log/*.log | awk '{print $5,$9}'
>       123456 /var/log/xinetd.log

If you want it separated with some other char:

> : ls -l /var/log/*.log | awk '{print $5","$9}'
>       123456,/var/log/xinetd.log