# How do I store the human-friendly size of a file in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, size

Basically what I want to do is to make a script that will output all the files and their sizes in the directory which have size more than a threshold value (2.2 GB in my case). I tried using the stat command as below

```
a=$(stat -c '%s' example.txt)
```

but this will store the file size in bytes. What I want is to store and display the size in human readable format(MB,GB). I was also thinking to store the output of `ls -lah` and then trim the result so as to store only name and size but that seemed a tedious task. Is there other anyway to do this apart from storing the result in bytes and then doing arithmetic operations on it.

Comment: there's the du command, the -h flag will print a human readable version. the -c flag will print a total size of all listed files.

Comment: What are some examples of the format you’d like? Should it always use the largest unit? Floating point ? To how many digits of precision?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44040/117549

Answer (score 9):

Since you're already using GNU tools, see `numfmt` from GNU coreutils:

```
$ stat -c %s file
310776
$ stat -c '%s' file | numfmt --to=si
311K
$ stat -c '%s' file | numfmt --to=iec
304K
$ stat -c '%s' file | numfmt --to=iec-i
304Ki
$ stat -c '%s' file | numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
311KB
```

With `ksh93`:

```
$ size=$(stat -c %s file)
$ printf "%#d %#i\n" "$size" "$size"
311k 304Ki
```

Or if built with the `ls` builtin (which you can also get as a standalone utility in the [ast-open](https://github.com/att/ast) package):

```
$ type ls
ls is a shell builtin version of /opt/ast/bin/ls
$ ls -Z '%#(size)d %#(size)i' file
311k 304Ki
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for a script, just use `du -d 0 -t 2200M -h /some/dir/name/*`.

Example.  Use `du` to show all files in */bin* greater than *500K*:

```
du -d 0 -t 500K -h /bin/*
```

Output:

```
1.1M    /bin/bash
620K    /bin/btrfs
2.0M    /bin/busybox
1.6M    /bin/ksh93
788K    /bin/zsh
```

`sort` has a complimentary `-h` that will sort the above by size:

```
du -d 0 -t 500K -h /bin/* | sort -h
```

Output:

```
620K    /bin/btrfs
788K    /bin/zsh
1.1M    /bin/bash
1.6M    /bin/ksh93
2.0M    /bin/busybox
```

Comment: you need to set `-d 1` to get the files and the summary includes directories.

Comment: @bu5hman, `-d 1` would include files from the first set of subdirectories, which the *OP* does not require.  If files from all subdirs were required, then removing the `-d 0` would be simpler.

Comment: my error. As you had typed the path `pathToDir/*` then `-d 0` works. While I had typed `pathToDir/` without the wildcard and this requires `-d 1`. At least on my system.

Comment: Note that `du` reports disk usage, not size. You could add `--apparent-size` for that. But for files of type _directory_, that would still include the size of all entries in the directory (recursively unless you add the `-S` option). `-S --exclude='/bin/*'` in combination with `LC_ALL=C` would help. It should also be noted that most of those options are GNU extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The kind person [HERE](http://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/find_all_large_files_linux_system) presents a solution that should help you:

```
find . -type f -size +2G -exec ls -sh {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

will give you the fully qualified path name and size in human readable form, all nicely sorted.

If you want *2.2G* then `find` won't handle the decimal, so you will have to do a bit of math and use *(2048 + 205 =) 2253M*

```
find . -type f -size +2253M -exec ls -sh {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

You can constrain the depth of the search and required size with the parameters of `find`, (see `man find`), and use `awk` to output your columns into a file or array.

Edit: -lh changed to -sh and awk removed as per @Olorin improvement

Comment: So going down a unit (G to M) and doing the math looks the better option. Thanks @steeldriver for that.

Comment: Use `-sh` instead of `-lh`. `-s` prints just the size, so you don't need the awk after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
du -h example.txt|cut -f 1
```

(`-h` = *human readable*)

This is under the assumption that *your* idea of "human readability" and *du*'s idea of this concept is the same.