# Human-readable `du` with finer grain

Tags: disk-usage, output, text-formatting, options, units

I sometimes wish human-readable `du -h` option to be more *fine-grained* while still human-readable.

Instead of showing:

```
 14G
```

it would show something like:

```
14G 236M 788k 110b
```

Is there an easy / straightforward / standard way to get this?

Comment: What is `o` in `110o`?

Comment: Just get the source code and modify to your needs.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk probably 'octet', french for 'byte'

Comment: @Carpette: it can be, thx

Comment: @ridgy Of course, even though I do not consider this "an easy way" yet ;)

Comment: This can help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1?rq=1

Comment: @Carpette Hm. This is not "an easy way" either, but I could write my own version of this `awk` function and pipe `du` output to it.. why not. Thanks :)

Comment: Following your last comment: you may also consider wrapping the piped `du` and `awk` in a shell function called `du`

Comment: @WeijunZhou for sure. We're still getting closer from [ridgy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/183587/)'s suggestion "get into the source code".. maybe it's the way to go :)

Comment: Of course you can do it the "hard way" with bash scripting, awk, ... But be aware you have to consider all the possible different options and outputs of `du`: `du -hs`, `du -hc`, `du --si`, etc. This is why I think of modifying the source might be easier.

Comment: @ridgy And I do think you're right. Would I need to recompile all `coreutils` then?

Comment: I think so. Depending on your OS/distribution (you did not tell about) get the full sources of coreutils, then modify `./lib/human.c` (and probably `./lib/human.h`) as this is the function library used, and then do a `configure`and `make`. All those coreutils now will have that human readable format you defined, but as long as you do no `make install` that doesn't harm.

Comment: Looked a bit deeper in the sources. You'ld probably have to modify `human.h` for the new buffer length `LONGEST_HUMAN_READABLE`, and then either modify after target `do_grouping` or the full function `human_readable`.

Comment: @ridgy Well, cheers for this insight :D I will probably not get into this soon, but it could be fun. Would this patch be good to offer for future `coreutils` releases?

Comment: If I were doing this, I would write a utility (say in awk, perl, or python) that converted a control statement parameter, and if no parameter was present, read from STDIN. The reason is that there are probably a number of situations where you might want the expanded output. So not just "du -s | new_utility", but also "ANY_command | new_utility". And the pipeline could be easily put into a script or a function. Many birds with one stone generality ... cheers,

Comment: @drl I like the idea. However, we would have to deal with, say, columns adjustment not to break it while `ls -la | new_utility`.. and in the same pipeline, how would we discriminate between filesizes and filecounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there seems to be **no** easy / straightforward / standard way to do this yet.

Alternative options are (credits to [ridgy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/183587/)'s, [Carpette](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/83944/carpette)'s, [Weijun Zhou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/259023/weijun-zhou)'s and [drl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/230570/drl)'s comments :):

- write a dedicated small converter utility in bash/awk/python/*etc.* so that:

  ```
  $ echo "789456" | utility  
  770K 976o
  ```

  Then pipe it to convert `du` output. You can inspire from this [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/)
  question. If it runs well, it could also parse the output of any command piped to it like:

  ```
  $ du -s | utility
  $ ls -la | utility
  ```

  You can even alias it forever on you machine to:

  ```
  duH() du -s $@ | utility
  ```

  - **pros:** Easy to write in any language you prefer.
  - **cons:** difficult to adapt to any command options (`du -s`, `du -hc`, `du
    --si`). Any command output (`ls -lah`, `rsync`) has to be parsed for
    finding digits strings meant to represent bytes and transformed without
    breaking the layout.
- get into [`coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) source code and add a new relevant option suiting your
  needs. You'll probably have to have a glance at `./lib/human.c`. Then once
  modified, it'll be a matter of `./configure`, `make`, `make install` so the
  `du` on your machine will now have this option implemented.

  - **pros:** quite straightforward, fast and integrated. May be offered as a
    future patch to standard `du` ?
  - **cons:** you'll have to get into existing `C` code and understand it first
    not to break it. You'll have to reinstall your own version of `coreutils` on any
    machine you need to use it.

For now, I'm not getting into this soon. Anyway, feel free to post here your own
pieces of solutions or alternatives workarounds as they come :)