# How to find the right memory size?

Tags: linux, memory, meminfo

We have a Linux machine with 32G. We capture the mem as follows:

```
mem=` cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}' `
echo $mem
32767184
```

and now we convert it to GIGA:

```
mem_in_giga=`  echo $(( $mem / 1024 / 1024)) `
echo $mem_in_giga
31
```

but from the results we get 31 and not 32G.

The same story with the `free` command:

```
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31           9          17           0           4          20
Swap:             7           0           7
```

So how do we get "32G" from any command?

Comment: You don't have a machine with 32 GB RAM. You have machine with approximately 32 GB RAM. If you really want `32`: `echo $((32767184/1000/1000))`.

Comment: Also, it's unclear what numbers are GB and what number may be GiB.

Comment: `free -g` outputs gibibytes, all the values quoted from output in the question are gibibytes. That’s appropriate since RAM capacities are bought in gibibyte or tebibyte increments...

Comment: Just FYI, you can get rid of the `cat`, `grep`, and `echo`: `awk '$1 == "MemTotal:" { print $2 / 1024 / 1024 }' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: For future reference on converting byte values, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44040/85039

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MemTotal` [shows](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html)

> Total usable RAM (i.e., physical RAM minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary
>                        code).

You can’t use that to determine the exact installed memory, except by using heuristics...

To determine the actual installed memory, you should use `lshw` or `dmidecode` which will show the size of the installed modules; *e.g.* from `lshw`:

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 4c
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 32GiB
      capabilities: ecc
      configuration: errordetection=ecc
```

or in more compact form (`lshw -class memory -short`):

```
H/W path           Device      Class          Description
=========================================================
/0/0                           memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/47/48                       memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/47/49                       memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/47/4a                       memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/4c                          memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/4c/0                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/4c/1                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/4c/2                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/4c/3                        memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
```