# Rounding a number in awk

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I’m trying to find a way to round up a few numbers.

The topic I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395284/round-a-divided-number-in-bash

I am using the following command in my bash script..

> free -h | gawk '/Mem:/{print $2}' | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1 "B"}')

The following code will show me how much in total Memory i have installed. Currently, im getting 3.7GB.
The problem is, i need this to be rounded up to 4GB.

I have a script that requests my machine a bunch of info and will echo it all out. (Prolly should use something different but haven't tried anything else yet as this is one of my projects that i am working on.

> memory=$(free -h | gawk '/Mem:/{print $2}' | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1 "B"}')
>
> echo $memory

Right now it echo's out 3.7GB as mentioned below.
I'v tried it different ways but can't seem to get it to 4GB.

Comment: This doesn’t address your rounding question, but see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421193/86440) to correctly determine the amount of installed memory.

Comment: Sadly can't install new software. I need to use the ones that come with  Debian.

Comment: `dmidecode` is priority important so it should be present on most Debian systems. You can’t guarantee you’ll get the correct result from `free` (especially `free -h` — *e.g.* on systems with 10 GiB of RAM or more, it will lose a full gibibyte).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
memory=$(
  LC_ALL=C free -h | awk '
    /^Mem/ {
      suffix = $2
      sub(/[0-9.]*/, "", suffix)
      printf "%.0f%sB\n", $2, suffix
    }'
)
```

(`LC_ALL=C` to make sure the numbers are printed using the `.` decimal radix (3.7G would be output as 3,7G in locales using comma as the decimal radix)).

On GNU/Linux systems, you can also do:

```
memory=$(
  awk '/^MemTotal/{print $2*1024}' < /proc/meminfo |
    numfmt --to=iec --format=%0f --suffix=B
)
```

Or:

```
memory=$(
  free -h | awk '/^Mem/{print $2}' |
    numfmt --from=iec --to=iec --format=%0f --suffix=B
)
```

(that one coping with locales where the decimal radix is not `.`).

Note that `free` on Linux reports that `MemTotal` field of /proc/meminfo. As per proc(5), that's the  *total usable RAM (i.e., physical RAM minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code)*. For the physical RAM, and for PCs, as pointed out by @StephenKit, you may be better off using `dmidecode` to get the information from the BIOS, though you'd need superuser privileges for that:

```
physical_memory=$(
  sudo dmidecode -t memory |
    awk '$1 == "Size:" && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $2$3}' |
    numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B |
    awk '{total += $1}; END {print total}' |
    numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format=%0f
)
```

Comment: Sadly this still gives me 3.7GB

Comment: @TheSebM8. How come? Does your `awk` print 3.7 for `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.0f\n", 3.7}'`?

Comment: @TheSebM8 You probably made a typo in that case.

Comment: @kusalanda no, i did notmake any typos. I copied what Stephane gave me. StéphaneChazelas that one does round it to 4.

Comment: @TheSebM8, is it possible that you get `3,7G` instead of `3.7` (see edit)? Otherwise, like Kusalananda, I can't explain it other than with a typo.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas All of the commands you gave worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @StephenKitt, under what  condition would they underestimate by 1 GiB (other than 1.1T rounded to 1T?)

Comment: Won't be having any server with over 1 TB RAM, so i'd say this works good :P

Comment: Basically there’s no fool-proof way to go from `MemTotal` to the amount of memory really installed. You need something like `dmidecode` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas how would you put your LC_ALL command into a bash script so if you " printf $memory it would print ut the result?

Comment: @TheSebM8, see edit

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "3.7" | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 0.5)}'
4
```

Comment: Can't use it like this. I need a way that does it for every different machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round to 2 decimal, here are some simple examples:

```
echo "12345.12345" | nawk '{printf ("%.2f\n", $1+0.005)}'
echo "12345.345" | nawk '{printf ("%.2f\n", $1+0.005)}'
```