# How to calculate total disk space using df?

Tags: shell-script, disk-usage

How do I modify the `df -h` command to add the results of following command (in other words, add them all together and return the result)?

```
$ df -h | awk '{print $2}'
Size
5.8G
64G
93M
3.9G
12G
108G
16G
134G
3.7T
3.7T
6.0T
```

Comment: Note that what you're asking isn't necessarily related to the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The human-readable formatting of the numbers gets in the way, so you need to have consistent output first. Portably, you can use `-P` option to output in blocks of 1024

```
df -P | awk 'NR>2{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

If you use GNU `df` you can specify `--blocksize` option:

```
df --block-size=1  | awk 'NR>2{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

`NR>2` portion is to avoid dealing with the `Size` header line. As for formatting data back into human readable format, if you are on Linux you can use `numfmt` tool, otherwise - implement converter in `awk`. See the [related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44040/85039).

Note also that `df` outputs sizes for all filesystems, including virtual filesystems such as `udev` and `tmpfs`. You might consider filtering those out if you want the actual physical disks only. So if we consider only filesystems that have a device file represented in `/dev/` filesystem, you could probably use something like this:

```
df -P | awk 'NR>2 && /^\/dev\//{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

With GNU `df` you could consider using `--local` flag as well, to ignore remove filesystems.

Comment: +1. with GNU `df` you can also use `-x` to exclude some filesystems.  e.g. `-x tmpfs -x devtmpfs`

Answer (score 11):

GNU `df` can do the totalling by itself, and recent versions (at least since 8.21, not sure about older versions) let you select the fields to output, so:

```
$ df -h --output=size --total
 Size
 971M
 200M
  18G
 997M
 5.0M
 997M
  82M
  84M
  84M
 200M
  22G
$ df -h --output=size --total | awk 'END {print $1}'
22G
```

From [`man df`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/df.1.html):

```
--output[=FIELD_LIST]
      use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields
      if FIELD_LIST is omitted.
--total
      elide  all entries insignificant to available space, and produce
      a grand total
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (ie btrfs) a filesystem appears multiple times in df. So a better sulution is

```
 df | awk '/dev\/sd/ {sums[$1]=$3} END {for (i in sums) tot += sums[i]; print tot}' | numfmt --to=iec
```