# How to sort human readable size

Tags: find, ls, sort

I'm basically looking for files then sorting by the size.  The script works if I don't sort the size by human readable.  But I want the size to be human readable.  How can I sort sizes that are human readable?

For example:

```
 ls -l | sort -k 5 -n | awk '{print $9 " " $5}'
```

This works as expected, I got the size of my files in bytes ascending:

```
1.txt 1
test.txt 3
bash.sh* 573
DocGeneration.txt 1131
andres_stuff.txt 1465
Branches.xlsx 15087
foo 23735
bar 60566
2016_stuff.pdf 996850
```

Now, I want the size to be human readable, so I added an -h parameter to ls, and now some files are out of order:

```
 ls -lh | sort -k 5 -n | awk '{print $9 " " $5}'
```

```
1.txt 1
DocGeneration.txt 1.2K
andres_stuff.txt 1.5K
test.txt 3
Branches.xlsx 15K
foo 24K
bar 60K
bash.sh* 573
2016_stuff.pdf 974K
```

Comment: `-k 5` — how does that work?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I believe the size is in the 5th column of the `ls` output

Comment: Using `du` instead of `ls` could be a good idea.

Comment: ... or `find`’s `-printf` with its `%p` and `%s` formatters (followed by a “humanisation” of the sizes).

Comment: @Jesse_b my error, I just assumed that the data in the question (marked as this is what I got) was the sorted input.I was wrong.

Comment: GNU ls takes -S to sort by largest file first, or -rS to sort by smallest first

Comment: See also [A standard tool to convert a byte-count into human KiB MiB etc; like du, ls1
](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1) which lets you sort pure numbers and then change to numbers with suffixes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try `sort -h k2`

> -h, --human-numeric-sort
>             compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

It is part of gnu sort, BSD sort, and others.

Comment: Shouldn't parsing the output of `ls` be avoided?

Comment: Thanks.  This actually solved my problem.  I had to move the sort command to the end because I was having some errors.  Now my solution looks like this: find . -type f -size -1024k -exec ls -ahl {} \; | awk '{print $9 " " $5}' | cut -c 3- | column -t | sort -k 2 -h.

Comment: @Tomasz Not always. If it provides the output you need, piping it to another formatting operation is not particularly dangerous. What you should not do is *loop* over the output of `ls`, and instead use file globbing directly. Globbing alone won't work here. That said, I would probably prefer `du` for this.

Comment: @Bloodgain the ls format is not guaranteed to be the same across systems/ls binaries, so parsing it portably is considered impossible.

Comment: Also, filenames with whitespace will mangle things

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble OK, then, just tell me another good way to get the same results as `ls -l | grep -v ^l | wc -l` (a count of all non-symlink files in the current directory). This is even the way the TLDP Bash How-To recommends counting files.

Comment: @Bloodgain : `files=(); for f in *; do [[ -L "$f" ]] && files+=("$f"); done; echo ${#files[@]}` (I might have the is a symlink test switch wrong). If you don’t care about symlinks, `files=(*); echo ${#files[@]}`, which becomes portable if you use `set` and not arrays.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble A bit complex for something that's more or less guaranteed to work with `ls` on any system, but I approve of your excellent bash-fu. As a function/alias, I would want to avoid creating the `files` variable, but the approach should be similar to just create a counter. Now that I'm thinking about it, I bet you could do something clever with the piped output of `echo *` or `find . -maxdepth 1`, but you'd need to handle some special cases.

Answer (score 29):

`ls` has this functionality built in, use the `-S` option and sort in reverse order: `ls -lShr`

```
       -r, --reverse
              reverse order while sorting

       -S     sort by file size, largest first
```

Comment: `-h` is not a [standard `ls` option](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html#tag_20_73_04), but must be usable if OP already has it.  The rest are standard, and it's certainly the answer I would have written.

Comment: +1 Don't mess around parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: This is the best answer, but it should include the info in @Toby's comment: `-S` might not be available for your `ls`. FWIW, `-S` is supported even with Emacs's library`ls-lisp.el`, which is used when the OS has no `ls`. It works in Emacs on MS Windows, for example.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @scatter, `ls` isn't the only program that can output human-readable sizes.  Knowing how to sort the output of something like `du` is useful.

Comment: This is the only correct answer here

Comment: @Drew: Toby's comment says that `-h` may not be universally available, but OP is already using it anyway. `-S` really *should* be universally available, because it's in the POSIX link that Toby provides. However, quite a few non-POSIX toolkits do exist out there.

Comment: @Drew: That's what affects *Emacs users on Windows*. I daresay WSL is a bigger audience.

Comment: @Kevin: `ls-lisp.el` is used by default on Windows. But any user, on *any platform* can use it. And it does support `hS`.

Comment: @Drew: No, it isn't, *by default*, used on Windows (I just tried it). `cmd.exe` thinks there's no such thing as `ls` ("'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."). PowerShell has `ls` as an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, which is written in .Net and has nothing to do with Lisp or Emacs. WSL, depending on distro, most likely has some variation of GNU coreutils installed, or perhaps BusyBox. The only way you get `ls-lisp.el` is if you choose to install Emacs, which is decidedly not the normal meaning of "used by default on Windows."

Comment: @kevin: By *"`ls-lisp.el` is used by default on Windows"* I of course meant that it is used by default **in Emacs** on Windows. If you do not use Emacs then I cannot imagine that you will use or care about Emacs-Lisp library `ls-lisp.el`. Using vanilla Emacs (i.e., `emacs -Q`) on Windows uses `ls-lisp.el` for Dired. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Drew: Neither the question nor this answer have anything to do with Emacs, so I don't see why you keep insisting it's relevant.

Comment: @kevin: I said "FWIW" in my original comment, and specifically said that `ls-lisp.el` is for use with Emacs. But I retract my second comment, which said that it would be good here to mention `ls-lisp.el`. You're right that the Q is not about use in Emacs. I've deleted that comment. (Nevertheless, you *can* use Emacs on any platform to get `-S`, if `-S` is not available on that platform.) Thx.

Comment: ```ls -S``` doesn't help if you also need directory sizes. There you need something like ```du -hs *|sort -h```

Answer (score 5):

Since no specific shell was mentioned, here's how to do the whole thing in the `zsh` shell:

```
ls -lhf **/*(.Lk-1024oL)
```

The `**` glob pattern matches like `*` but across `/` in pathnames, i.e. like a recursive search would do.

The `ls` command would enable human readable sizes with `-h`, and long list output format with `-l`.  The `-f` option disables sorting, so `ls` would just list the files in the order they are given.

This order is arranged by the `**/*(.Lk-1024oL)` filename globbing pattern so that the smaller files are listed first.  The `**/*` bit matches every file and directory in this directory and below, but the `(...)` modifies the glob's behaviour (it's a "glob qualifier").

It's the `oL` at the end that orders (`o`) the names by file size (`L`, "length").

The `.` at the start makes the glob only match regular files (no directories).

The `Lk-1024` bit selects files whose size is less than 1024 KB ("length in KB less than 1024").

If `zsh` is not your primary interactive shell, then you could use

```
zsh -c 'ls -lf **/*(.Lk-1024oL)'
```

Use `setopt GLOB_DOTS` (or `zsh -o GLOB_DOTS -c ...`) 
to also match hidden names.   ... or just add `D` to the glob qualifier string.

---

Expanding on the above, assuming that you'd want a 2-column output with pathnames and human readable sizes, and also assuming that you have `numfmt` from GNU coreutils,

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

for pathname in **/*(.Lk-1024oL); do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$pathname" "$(zstat +size "$pathname" | numfmt --to=iec)"
done
```

or, quicker,

```
paste <( printf '%s\n' **/*(.Lk-1024oL) ) \
      <( zstat -N +size **/*(.Lk-1024oL) | numfmt --to=iec )
```

Answer (score 4):

If your `sort` does not have the `-h` option you could use an (albeit very long) awk command like the following:

```
find . -type f -size -1024k -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -k 5 -n | awk '{if ($5 > 1099511627776) {print $9,$5/1024/1024/1024/1024"T"} else if ($5 > 1073741824) {print $9,$5/1024/1024/1024"G"} else if ($5 > 1048576) {print $9,$5/1024/1024"M"} else if ($5 > 1024) {print $9,$5/1024"K"} else {print $9,$5"B"}}' | column -t
```

This will sort your output in bytes and then convert them to their human readable size afterward.

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($5<=1024) {print}}' | sort -k 5 -n | awk '{print $9"\t"substr($5/1024,1,3)"k"} '| column -t
```

The first `awk` exp will look for the files lesser than 1M and the second one will take the byte size from the result and convert it to the KB and prints the first 3 elements to give a human-readable size.

Comment: That does not really solve OPs question - it only looks in the current directory and will only print regular files.  Also will compare against 1Kb instead of 1MB.  Finally we are after answers with some explanation about why the code works.

Comment: My bad added what it does.