# How to list all users and their total consumed space in multiple drives

Tags: linux, shell

How to list all users and their total consumed space in multiple drives and just for a specific file extension? Basically similar to the output below:

```
User1 15T /datadrive01
User2 10T /datadrive01
User3 11gb /datadrive01

User1 20T /datadrive02
User2 10gb /datadrive02
User3 5gb /datadrive02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take a while:

```
for mnt in /datadrive01 /datadrive02; do
    find "$mnt" -printf '%u %k\n' 2>/dev/null \
      | awk -v "mnt=$mnt" '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (u in sum) print u,sum[u],mnt}' \
      | numfmt --from-unit=1000 --to=iec --field=2
    echo
done
```

- `find` all files and print user and disk usage of size (`-printf '%u %k\n'`)
- with `awk` sum up all sizes per user and print.
- with `numfmt` optionally convert sizes to  human-readable format
- `echo` just for the blank line in between

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and thanks for the script, it is working. However, where do I specify that the files I want to be searched are only those with a file extension of say, '.txt'?

Comment: add `-name "*.txt"` to the `find` command.

Comment: last question, if numfmt isnt available, is there an alternative?

Comment: see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259254/236063), also read the other answers.