# Sort a file based on 1 column

Tags: sort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do you sort du output by size?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-do-you-sort-du-output-by-size)

I have a text file generated from the output of

```
du --max-depth 1 -h > sizeOfHomeFolder.txt
```

It's contents are in this format:

```
$ cat sizeOfHomeFolder.txt  | head
776K    ./Expensemanager
8.0K    ./workspace
4.0M    ./mysql-tutorial
3.6M    ./temp
26M ./Desktop
4.0K    ./Ubuntu One
4.0K    ./Photos
4.0K    ./Public
```

I need to sort this file based on 1st column i.e. the size.

How to do this with `sort` or `sed` or any other common unix utility ?

Comment: [sort `du` output by size](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4681/9537) duplicate?

Comment: Thanks `cat file | sort -h` worked. As simple as that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a not too old version of GNU `sort`, you can do

```
sort -k 1,1h < input.txt
```

`-h` is for "human" sort and is required to know that 1.0M is indeed larger than 512K.

Comment: +1 for `sort -h`.  it's very useful, esp. for things like sorting `du -h`.  according to the changelog, `-h` was added to GNU sort on 2009-05-26