# How to sort files based on the json property value inside the file?

Tags: shell, command-line, json

I've downloaded list of videos via [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) and each file has corresponding .json file containing certain properties. So I would like to sort the files based on the selected json property which is inside of corresponding .json file (e.g. by number of views count, property: view_count).

What tools I need and how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use some [command-line JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser), extract the specific value for each file by printing it and sort it by the printed value.

Here is the example of the script which you can use:

```
ls -1 *.json | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 -L1 -I% sh -c "cat '%' | jshon -e view_count | awk '{print \$1\" %\"}'" | sort -k 1 -nr
```

Where `view_count` is your json property name.
The script will list the .json files and for each file will print the JSON view_count property value and numerically sort by the 1st column.

In this example, you need `jshon` tool which can be easily installed from the package manager. Or install it from the GitHub [source](https://github.com/keenerd/jshon).

Then you can freely modify the above script on your needs. Some examples:

- To print top 20, add: `| head -n20`
- To print corresponding videos instead of json files, add: `| sed s/info.json$/mkv/`

Links:

- [Unix command-line JSON parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858671/unix-command-line-json-parser)
- [How to parse JSON with shell scripting in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux)
- [Sort a file based on 1 column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46898/sort-a-file-based-on-1-column)

Answer (score 0):

I first create a intermediate tsv. Tools like `sort` and `cut` support tsv files by default.

I also suggest creating a single file with a JSON object per line. `jq` can handle these well.

```bsh
paste <(jq -rc .id < videos.json) <(jq -rc videos.json) | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -u | cut -f 2-
```

This will sort and remove duplicates while writing to `stdout`.

Links:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/