# Show human readable file size in du

Tags: osx, disk-usage

I'm using this command to determine which directory is eating my disk.

```
du -sk * | sort -n
```

How can I get human readable result form `du` for file sizes? I've checked `man` and all it have is `-k` flag which turns byte results to kilobyte results. I need results in gigabytes

Comment: For questions like this, you absolutely need to say which version of UNIX you're using (e.g. AIX 6.1, HP-UX 11i, Red Hat Linux, etc., etc.)

Comment: and also refer to the `man`(manual) pages.  `man du`

Comment: @EightBitTony lesson learned. I'm on OSX btw

Comment: How is `ls` related to this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may work:

```
du -hs * | sort -h
```

If your copy of `du` doesn't support the `-h` flag, then you can convert the numbers [using `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44087/26112).

```
du -ks * | awk '
function human(x) {
    s="kMGTEPYZ";
    while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
        {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
    return int(x+0.5) substr(s,1,1)
}
{gsub(/^[0-9]+/, human($1)); print}'
```

Comment: my `du` supports `-h`. works good but sort doesn't work as you expect now. 90G is smaller than 100K now!

Comment: Are you sure `sort -h` does not work? I use it all the time in combination with `du`

Comment: my sort doesn't have -h. I'm on OSX

Comment: I should have made a note about that. The `-h` flag isn't very portable. You can use the `awk` option and sort before humanizing the numbers. Or, take a look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4688/26112.

Answer (score 3):

On a Linux machine [Debian based], I get this when opening the man page for `du`:

```
 -h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Thus: `du -h` should give you what you need. Else, also from `man du`:

```
   --si   like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024

   -k     like --block-size=1K
```

I really wonder where you found your information.

Comment: Maybe the OP is using AIX, where du doesn't have a -h flag.  Or HP-UX.