# Installed coreutils on CentOS for sort --human-readable flag but it still doesn't work

Tags: centos, sort, coreutils

I'm trying to do [`du -h | sort -h`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81374/show-human-readable-file-size-in-du), but my CentOS 5.7 doesn't have `-h` flag for `sort`. [So](https://serverfault.com/a/156648/112378) I installed coreutils

> ```
> Updated:    
>   coreutils.x86_64 0:5.97-34.el5_8.1
> Complete!
> ```

yet `sort` still doesn't have the `-h` flag. Am I not doing something,or doing something wrong? I'm fairly new to *nix.

Comment: Following the link you gave, you need coreutils 7.5 and you only have 5.97  You need to seriously consider upgrading CentOS

Comment: @eyoung100 ah thanks! It's actually a VPS, not sure if I can do much about it.

Comment: Then you need to talk to your host...

Comment: Tell them you would like to upgrade to CentOS 6.5 at least

Answer (score 0):

The help page is obtained by using `sort --h`

or use the manual eg.

`man sort`