# Human-readable filesize with find's printf

Tags: bash, find, printf

I am writing a simple helper function to show a specific folder in the format I want:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "." -printf '[%TY-%Tm-%Td]\t%s\t%f\n' | sort -n
```

However I want to show the filesizes in a nicer format. I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-do-you-sort-du-output-by-size/4691#4691) which I used to create a bash function called `hr`.

```
user@host:~$ hr 12345
12M
```

I tried using this in the `find` call as so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "." -printf '[%TY-%Tm-%Td]\t'$(hr %s)'\t%f\n' | sort -n
```

But it still continues to show the full filesize. How should I modify this so it works as expected?

Comment: At first I'd like to offer you to use `-exec stat {} +` with desired format instead of `-printf`

Comment: @don_crissti I want it ordered by date (which is the first column). This is Ubuntu, but also using it on CentOS

Answer (score 9):

Assuming sane file names, with `numfmt` from `gnu coreutils` (`8.21` or later):

```
find . -type f -printf '[%TY-%Tm-%Td]\t%s\t%f\n' | numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i
```

You can further format the output via `--padding=` and `--format=` options (and with [most recent versions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74228) even set output precision) e.g:

```
... |  numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=8
```

or

```
... |  numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i  --format='%10.3f'
```

---

If you don't mind the permissions & links-count columns, with `gnu` `ls`:

```
ls -gohAt --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `-exec du` after your `-printf` ?

eg:

```
jon@local$ find . -maxdepth 1 -not -iname "." -printf '[%TY-%Tm-%Td]\t' -exec du -bh {} \;
[2015-04-01]    1.6K    ./main.go
[2015-04-01]    5.2K    ./main_test.go
```

Comment: how do i sort this?

Answer (score 2):

This will require some adaptation if you want to use it, but the `dc` utility incorporates a little known - if possibly very useful - feature of handling arbitrary output radices. It looks strange at first.

```
echo 1024o 1025p 1024p 1023p|dc
```

---

```
 0001 0001
 0001 0000
 1023
```

But its not too difficult to catch on.

```
ls -s  file;\
ls -hs file;\
echo 1024o 1048576p|dc
```

---

```
1048576 file
1.0G file
 0001 0000 0000
```

...and...

```
dd bs=1kx1k seek=500 of=file <>/dev/null 2>&0;\
ls -s  file;\
ls -hs file;\
echo 1024o 512000p|dc
```

---

```
512000
500M
 0500 0000
```

I'm partial to `dc`, but `bc` can do the same kind of thing, it's just not as straight-forward as I regard it.

Anyway, `dc` will not help you to handle your `find ... -printf` script - which I think you'll have to do an `-exec` at least to get it to work the way you want it to if you don't use `numfmt` as already suggested. But if you were to adapt to something a little more flexible and fleshed out like that, it could be very useful to you. In any case it can probably more easily do much of the job your `hr` function does.

Answer (score 0):

If fields order is not important

```
du --time --time-style=+[%F] -sh *
```

In other case you are free to reorder it by `sed` for example

```
… | sed 's/\(\S*\s*\)\(\S*\s*\)/\2\1/'
```