# “human readable” sizes with ls -sh on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ls

With GNU `ls` one can get "human readable" file sizes (this means suffixes like K, M, G, ... for Kilo-, Mega- and Gigabyte etc. are appended and the number is kept below 1024) with the option `-h` even if *not* used in conjunction with `-l` but only with `-s`.

How can one get this behavior with the `ls` that comes with FreeBSD, i.e. how does one get `ls -sh` to work in FreeBSD?

Comment: `alias ls="ls -h"`

Comment: AFAIK, GNU `ls` does not output "human readable" sizes without `-h`.

Comment: it does, with `ls -sh`. The manual says `h, --human-readable: with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)`

Comment: But the `ls` on my OS X doesn't support that combination. Don't know about FreeBSD. (Obvious workaround: install GNU ls)

Comment: @ilkkachu:   the manual says `-h      When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes`. It does not work out of the box in FreeBSD.

Comment: Yeah, I meant GNU ls, which @Kusalananda mentioned, sorry.

Comment: I just tried all I said, and it worked (in both default `csh` and in `bash`). If you say what version of FreeBSD and which login shell you are using, we will help.

Comment: BTW, give us the output of `echo $TERM` please.

Comment: A plain `ls -h` doesn't display *any* size whatsoever. Only `ls -s` and `ls -l` display sizes.

Answer (score 4):

The way to answer this is to read the source code:

- FreeBSD `ls` uses the `-h` option in a couple of places. It does this first when it [needs statistics for a file](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/ls.c?view=markup#l880).
- [It needs statistics when doing a](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/ls.c?view=markup#l621) "longform" (`-l`), inode (`-i`) or size (`-s`) option, to compute the width of the largest number.
- [If none of those options are set](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/ls.c?view=markup#l888), it doesn't use the `-h` option.
- It combines the `-h` with `-i` and/or `-s` [when doing a long listing (`-l`)](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/print.c?revision=291959&view=markup#l224), specifically when it [prints sizes](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/print.c?revision=291959&view=markup#l762).  Otherwise, it is ignored.

No error is reported if `-h` is given without any of those options.

[FreeBSD added the option in 2001](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=88591), well before the (rather old) userland in OSX.  The FreeBSD and OSX manual pages have identical descriptions of `-h` (and "ls -lh" works for both).  But at that point, it only worked with `-l`:

> Add a new flag, **`-h`** which when combined with the **`-l`** option causes
>   file sizes to be displayed with unit suffixes; Byte, Kilobyte,
>   Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the
>   number of digits to three or less.

Answer (score 0):

If you want GNU ls features on FreeBSd, you can install the [gnuls package](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/misc/gnuls/) and alias `ls` to `gnuls`.

If you want to stick to the base software, you can post-process the output of `ls`. (Script reposted from [how do you sort du output by size?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-do-you-sort-du-output-by-size/4691#4691)) This works on any POSIX system.

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls | awk '
    function human(x) {
        s="kMGTEPYZ";
        while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
            {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
        return int(x+0.5) substr(s,1,1)
    }
    {gsub(/^[0-9]+/, human($1)); print}'
```

`CLICOLOR_FORCE` causes BSD `ls` to use colors even if it isn't writing to a terminal. On the other hand, because `ls` isn't writing to a terminal, you'll get one file per line instead of columns. On FreeBSD, you can use the option `-C` to get columns, but then the postprocessing script becomes a lot more complex since it needs to find sizes in the middle of the line. Try this (untested):

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -C | awk '
    function human(x) {
        s="kMGTEPYZ";
        while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
            {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
        return int(x+0.5) substr(s,1,1)
    }
    {gsub(/(^|  )[0-9]+/, human($1)); print}'
```