# Break down directory by file extension and get total size and count for each

Tags: find, command

I have a directory (e.g. `/home/various/`) with many subdirectories (e.g. `/home/various/foo/`, `/home/various/ber/`, `/home/various/kol/` and `/home/various/whatever/`).

Is there a command I can run, which will breakdown the contents per file extension showing totals like

- total size
- number of files

Let's say, I don't want to manually type each file extension in the terminal, in part because I don't know all the file extensions inside (recursively) `/various/`.

An output like this, would be great:

```
*.txt 23 files, 10.2MB
*.pdf 8 files, 23.2MB
*.db 3 files, 2.3MB
*.cbz 24 files, 2.3GB
*.html 2,508 files, 43.9MB
*.readme 13 files, 4KB
```

Comment: Are extensions case-sensitive, i.e. `.pdf` is different than `.PDF`?   What about files that have no extensions?

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic code

```
duext() {

case "$1" in
  -* )
    set "./$1"
esac   

POSIXLY_CORRECT= find "${1-.}" -type f -exec du {} + | awk '
{
  sz=$1
  $1=""
  sub("^ *","")
  sub("^.*/","")
  sub("^\\.","")
  w=split($0,a,".")
  e=tolower(w==1?"*":"*."a[w])
  s[e]+=sz
  n[e]+=1
}
END {
  for (e in s) print 512*s[e]"\t"n[e]"\t"e
}'
}
```

Usage: `duext path`. The default `path` is `.`. The function should work in `sh` and compatible shells.

The function generates lines in the following form:

```
s<tab>n<tab>e
```

where `s` is disk size used (in bytes), `n` is the number of files, `e` is the extension. This is different from your requested output because I decided to optimize for parsing. What you call "extension" is just a part of the filename in *nix. Filenames may contain spaces or tabs. Placing `e` (that may contain spaces or tabs) at the end of the line allows us to recognize other fields reliably. E.g. you can sort by size easily:

```
duext /home/various/ | sort -rn -k1,1       # optionally: … | column -t
```

Notes:

- Newline characters in pathnames will make the results incorrect.
- `POSIXLY_CORRECT= du …` is a portable way to get disk size used. It reports in units of 512 bytes, therefore `512*s[e]` later in the `awk` code. GNU `du` provides some interesting options (e.g. `--apparent-size`); they may require adjusting the `awk` code.
- `sub("^\\.","")` is responsible for not treating the leading dot in the name as the extension separator. In effect `.nfo` is interpreted as a (hidden) file without extension rather than a file with `nfo` extension. If this is not what you want, remove the line.
- The code tells apart empty extension (e.g. `foo.`) from no extension (`foo`). The former is reported as `*.`; the latter is reported as `*`.
- The code is case-insensitive. Remove `tolower` to make it case-sensitive.
- Hardlinks can distort the result. Your `du` may or may not omit a file if it's a hardlink to some already accounted file. Additionally `find … -exec du {} +` runs `du` as many times as it needs (to avoid `argument list too long`) and hardlinked files may or may not be passed to the same `du`. You can force counting every single hardlink by using `du -l` (non-portable option in GNU `du`) or portably by running one `du` per file: `find … -exec du {} \;`. To reliably count hardlinks just once, you need a different approach (single instance of GNU `du` and `--files0-from=`?). In general it's possible to have hardlinks with different extensions. This is not a problem when you want to count each hardlink separately, but if you want to count them as one file then it's indeterminate which extension to assign.

---

#### Customizing format

I'm not sure if by `MB` you mean [mebibytes or megabytes](https://superuser.com/q/373579/432690), I assume the latter. The following code should translate to the format you want:

```
yourformat() { awk '
  function human(x) {
    if (x<1000) {return x} else {x/=1000}
    s="kMGTEPZY";
    while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
      {x/=1000; s=substr(s,2)}
    return int(10*x+0.5)/10 substr(s,1,1)
  }
  {
    s=$1; n=$2
    $1=""; $2=""
    sub("^  ","")
    print $0" "n" file"(n==1?"":"s")", "human(s)"B"
  }'
}
```

(Note: `human(x)` was taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4691/108618) and adjusted.)

Use it like this:

```
duext /home/various/ | yourformat
```

`duext` uses `awk` internally and now we're piping it to `yourformat` which also uses `awk`. Overall we could use single `awk` in a single function instead. Still separate  `awk`s allow us to put e.g. `sort …` in between (in a single shell function or in a pipe between functions). While some kind of sorting can be implemented in `awk` (or at least in GNU `awk`), there is no point in reinventing the wheel. IMO keeping the output from the first `awk` easily parsable is the right thing. This way you can apply *any* filter and formatting later.

Let's improve your format, so `column -t` can be used. And how about a factor of 1024?

```
myformat() { awk '
  function human(x) {
    if (x<1000) {return x" "} else {x/=1024}
    s="kMGTEPZY";
    while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
      {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
    return int(10*x+0.5)/10" "substr(s,1,1)"i"
  }
  {
    s=$1; n=$2
    $1=""; $2=""
    sub("^  ","")
    print $0"\t"n" file"(n==1?"":"s")"\t"human(s)"B"
  }'
}
```

And then:

```
duext /home/various/ | sort -nr -k1,1 | myformat | column -t -s "$(printf '\t')"
```

Notes:

- `"$(printf '\t')"` is a portable way to get a tab character. In some shells (e.g. in Bash) `$'\t'` does the same.
- `column` itself is not portable.
- Extensions with tab characters will break the formatting. They are rather rare though.

Frankly I like this solution enough to keep it. I created a script named `due` for future use:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

duext() {
  …
}

myformat {
  …
}

duext "${1-.}" | sort -nr -k1,1 | myformat | column -t -s "$(printf '\t')"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very interesting question, the best I can build is this script:

```bsh
set -e
# set -x

folder=$1
counter=$(tempfile)

# List file extensions
list_extensions() {
  find "$folder" -type f |
  while read filename
  do
    basename=${filename##*/}
    ext=${basename##*.}
    echo ${ext,,}  # downcase extensions to prevent duplicates
  done |
  sort -u
}

list_extensions |
while read extension
do
  size=$(find "$folder" -type f -iname "*.$extension" -fprintf $counter . -print0 |
    du -hc --files0-from=- | tail -n 1 | sed -E 's/\s+total//')
  count=$( wc -c < $counter )
  printf "*.%-10s\t%6s files\t%10s\n" "$extension" "$count" "$size"
done

rm $counter
```

It does not support complex filenames, there might be a lot of exceptions and performance is not great, but it does work.

Sample output:

```
*.wma              122 files          411M
*.wpl               16 files           64K
*.xls                2 files           24K
*.xlsx               1 files           28K
*.zip                5 files          333M
```